# How to get "remainder" of query (all non-matched pairs) in LINQ and collect it in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I am matching requests with responses based on requestId as follows:

```
    public void MatchCallPairsByRequestId()
    {
        // Finds request that have matching response based on RequestId and create callpair
       _callPairs = _requests.Where(req => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId))
                  .Join(_responses, 
                        req => req.RequestId,
                        resp => resp.RequestId,
                        (req, resp) => new CallPair(req, resp)).ToList();
    }
```

or in LINQ expression:

```
 _callPairs = (from req in _requests
                  join resp in _responses
                      on req.RequestId equals resp.RequestId
                      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId)
                  select new CallPair(req, resp)).ToList();
```

Now I want to collect the requests and responses that are not matched by the function in a separate list called `nonMatchedRequests` and `nonMatchedResponses`. How do I use this query to collect the remainder in a separate list?

Comment: How do you want to create pairs from unmatched items?

Comment: An outer join might be what you want: which has no dedicated LINQ method, but according to docs can be emulated using [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları ha nice one. I mean two lists: unmatched requests and unmatched responses.

Comment: @user2609980 In that case you might need to run two subsequent queries using `Except`, so `_requests.Except(_callPairs.Select(cp => cp.Request))` which will items from the first set that do not appear in the second. Do something similar with `_responses`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in one call or perhaps even merge it with producing the list of pairs, but you can run a couple of follow up methods to determine the unmatched items:

```
var unmatchedRequests = _requests.Except(_callPairs.Select(cp => cp.Request));

var unmatchedResponses = _responses.Except(_callPairs.Select(cp => cp.Response));
```

The documentation for `Enumerable.Join` also talks of being able to use `GroupJoin` to perform an outer join, as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will return unmatched requests, though I think it would miss unmatched responses.

<sup>I await with bated breath the answer demonstrating linq wizardry that does this more efficiently with one call.</sup>

Comment: Total calls= 8192, responses 4093, requests 4099, pairs 476. It finds 3629 unmatched requests and 3623 unmatched responses.

3629+3623 + 2*476 = 8204, 8204 > 8192 so somehow too many unmatched responses and requests get caught.

Comment: @user2609980 `Except` will use a default equality comparer, perhaps the equality check is wrong and you need to provide your own equality comparer? Also, your join could be incorrect or doing unexpected things?

Comment: It is compared on the basis of the string value of requestId. I will check what callpairs are created.

Comment: It is also possible to collect the requests and responses from a list and remove it from it if they are matched?

Comment: @user2609980 You can use the results of the join to determine what to remove from the other lists, but there are no standard LINQ methods that do removing, as its a query language. You'd just have to do that bit manually.

Comment: how would I use the results of the join to determine what to remove from the other lists?

Comment: @user2609980 The results of the join are the matched pairs, so you would iterate the other lists, check if they are in the join results somewhere, if they are, mark them for removal.

Comment: Nope. // The below queries are both empty so there are no matched requests/responses in unmatched            
            `var commonRequests = _unmatchedRequests.Intersect(selectedRequests);`
            `var commonResponses = _unmatchedResponses.Intersect(selectedResponses);`

            // and the one below are both 476 aas expected so there are no matched requests and responses not in call pairs            `var requestsInCallpairs = _callPairs.Select(cp => selectedRequests.Any(req => req == cp._request)).ToList();`

Comment: `var responsesInCallpairs = _callPairs.Select(cp => selectedResponses.Any(resp => resp == cp._response)).ToList();`

I have no idea why the total of unmatched requests and responses plus the amount of requests and responses in callpairs (matched response + request) are 12 bigger than the total amount of requests and responses.

Comment: Ah I see! There are duplicates in the selectedReuqests and selectedResponses. When I do `Distinct()` on the list the selectedRequests and selectedResponses the amounts become 470 (which is 6 less than 476). This means that the 12 too much comes from duplicates in requests and responses. The question now is how to remove them from _callPairs.

Answer (score 2):

Find requests and responses which don't exist in the returned CallPair objects

```
var unmatchedRequests = _requests.Where(req => !_callPairs.Any(cp => cp.Request == req));
var unmatchedResponses = _responses.Where(resp => !_callPairs.Any(cp => cp.Response == resp));
```

EDIT: here is some example code

```
var requests = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => "Request" + i).ToList();
var responses = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => "Response" + i).ToList();

var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Request" + i, "Response" + i * 2)).ToList();

var unmatchedRequests = requests.Where(req => !pairs.Any(cp => cp.Key == req));
var unmatchedResponses = responses.Where(resp => !pairs.Any(cp => cp.Value == resp));
```

I get 7 unmatched requests and 7 unmatched responses, which looks correct. Don't some of your requests are matched to multiple responses or vice versa?

Comment: Thanks. Total calls= 8192, responses 4093, requests 4099, pairs 476. It finds 3629 unmatched requests and 3623 unmatched responses. 3629+3623 + 2*476 = 8204, 8204 > 8192 so somehow too many unmatched responses and requests get caught.

Comment: That's strange, maybe some requests / responses are matched more than once? I added some code i used to check my answer. Perhaps you should check what pairs are created?

Answer (score 2):

You probably can do this through `.Except()`, maybe also operating on distinct values

```
// Matching pairs
_callPairs = _requests.Where(req => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId))
    .Join(
        _responses, 
        req => req.RequestId,
        resp => resp.RequestId, 
        (req, resp) => new CallPair(req, resp)
    ).ToList();

// To use the .Distinct() part, you're going to need to implement IEqualityComparer twice
// Easy but maybe not strictly necessary, no matter what it would be a solid approach
var matchedRequests = _callPairs.Select(cp => cp.Request); //.Distinct(new RequestComparer());
var matchedResponses = _callPairs.Select(cp => cp.Response); //.Distinct(new ResponseComparer());

var nonMatchingRequests = _requests.Except(matchedRequests);
var nonMatchingResponses = _responses.Except(matchedResponses);
```